# 2D array returning incompatible types using Iterator Pattern

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build a 2D array. To hold food items, with values. I know I am doing something wrong, can anyone see it?

```
public class FoodMenu implements Menu {

    static final int MAX_ITEMS = 6;
    int numberOfItems = 0;
    String[][] foodItems;

    public FoodMenu() {
        foodItems = new String[MAX_ITEMS][];
    
        addItem("Vegetarian BLT","Test");
        addItem("BLT","Test");
        addItem("Soup of the day","Test");
}

public FoodMenuIterator(String[][] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

public void addItem(String name, String value) {
        if (numberOfItems >= MAX_ITEMS) {
            System.err.println("Sorry, menu is full!  Can't add item to menu");
        } 
        else {
            foodItems[numberOfItems][3] = name;
            numberOfItems = numberOfItems + 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (position >= items.length || items[position] == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        String menuItem = items[position]; ---**//The issue is here**---
        position = position + 1;
        return menuItem;
    }
```

The issue is above on the commented line. The error comes up as incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String. My aim is to add type of food, and value as String in a 2d array.

How do I go about fixing this error?
I've tried giving "String menuItem = items[position][]; etc to have no solution."
Any ideas?

Comment: it should be `String menuItem = items[position][someIndex]` or `String[] menuItem = items[position];` depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: What does `addItem` do? What exactly does the stacktrace say?

Comment: Looks like `items` is 2D array so taking value at index `[position]` will return 1D array but you are trying to assign that array to `String menuItem = ..`. To better understand it take a look at 2d array like `int[][] numbers2D = { {1,2}, {3,4} }`. If you use `numbers2D[1]` it would return `{3,4}` *1D array* so you can't do something like `int num = numbers2D[1];` (what value should `num` hold: `3` or `4` or maybe something else? Such thing is unspecified so not allowed in Java language). What you can do is pick some element from that 1d array like `numbers2D[1][0]` which will return `3`.

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass  its to addItem to the array. I am trying to learn how to do the iterator pattern with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

you want to inherit from java's default iterator otherwise you aren't overriding anything. compiler thinks position is a local variable.

Comment: OP's implementing `Menu`, `@Override` refers to the interface methods

Comment: my bad i would make then the iterator a separate class that inherits the java iterator.

Comment: yes because position isn't defined anywhere. you want to turn the iterator into a class and incorporate all those functions in it. make the iterator extend java's iterator.